# How to solve an optimisation equation with unknown parameters?

Tags: optimization

Given an example equation:

$$ z = Mx + Ny $$

where $M$, $N$ are unknown parameters and $x, y, z$ are features of a dataset.

My initial guess is to use **gradient descent** and the **least squares error** to obtain $M$ and $N$ from the dataset.

After that, we construct the inequality equations and apply these with the new equation (known $M$ and $N$) to a **Lagrange multiplier** to minimise $z$.

Is this a correct approach to the problem?

Comment: What are features of a dataset?  Please do not use jargon from a specific field. Please state in what sets these variables and constants live.

Comment: Basically, it's an example dataset with features x, y and z where x and y are directly proportional to z.

Comment: I'm basically wondering if M and N need to be found first or do we just use Lagrange multiplier to minimise z given a set of constraints.

Comment: I don't even know if they are scalars, vectors, matrices, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have a data set $D=\{x_i,y_i,z_i\},\ \ i = 1,2\cdots,n$

so you can solve

$$
\min_{M,N}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(M x_i+N y_i-z_i\right)^2
$$

a typical least squares problem.

Comment: I see, so if constraints are involved then we would just use the Lagrange multiplier instead? There isn't any need to obtain M and N first.

Comment: If the constraints are linear the problem can be easily solved using a quadratic programming solver.